# Why doesn't it show my score is invalid when I enter a score?

Tags: c#

```
{
    using System;
    using static System.Console;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int score; //score
            int totalScore = 0;
            int count = 0;
            string message;
            WriteLine("Enter test scores:");
            message = ReadLine();
            score = Convert.ToInt32(message);
            count = ++count;
            totalScore += score; 
            while (score > 100) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid score, please enter a valid test score");
                message = Console.ReadLine();
                score = Convert.ToInt32(message);
                count = ++count;
                totalScore += score;
                while (score != -1) 
                {
                    WriteLine("Enter test scores:");
                    message = ReadLine();
                    score = Convert.ToInt32(message);
                    count = ++count; 
                    totalScore += score;
                }

                int average = totalScore / count; //the average 
                WriteLine("The average of all {0} scores is {1}", count, average);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run my code, if I enter an invalid score first, it shows it is invalid till I enter a valid one, and after I enter a valid score then try to enter an invalid score, it doesn't show it is invalid. Why?

Comment: Just a quick glance: you write `count = ++count;` in your code. Did you mean to write `count++;`?

Comment: @TylerPantuso - In this case ++count is equivalent to count++.   Because of operator precedence: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @SteveWellens Wow that's cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you first enter a invalid one, you enter the first while loop, and after when you enter an valid one you will run the while loop for your last time, thus entering the other while loop and once your done there you wont start over.

This is whats happening

While score is > 100, write invalid score and read a new score

If the new score still is > 100 run through the loop and start over.
But if the new score is < 100 continue the loop for the last time.